# Should I allow navigation to about:blank in my Ionic app?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Should I add `<allow-navigation href="about:blank" />` to config.xml in my Ionic 3 app? In iOS using WKWebView, I'm getting this error message in the Xcode console when I run the app:

`ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='about:blank'`

However, there is no adverse behaviour. Does the WKWebView just navigate to about:blank when it is instantiated?

Please explain.